# Linked project references aren't being copied to target folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, build-process

I have 2 c++ projects in a solution.
**ExecB** (an executable) depends on **ProjA** (a dll).

So in **ExecB**'s properties I add **ProjA** as a reference, and select **Copy Local = true**.
The problem is, ProjA's dll isn't being copied to ExecB's output folder folder.  So the executable obviously doesn't run.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

For C++ projects, the Visual Studio template/wizard sets the Output Directory to a subfolder of the solution: `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\`. This is so the [DLL Search Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) works well for the developer. It even works if you have added projects to the solution from outside the solution folder hierarchy; The build will put all binaries into the output folder for that solution.

If this isn't working, check the Output Directory property on all platform/configuration combinations of all your projects. Also make sure that the Build Configuration Manager shows that your selected solution build is building all the projects appropriate for the solution platform/configuration.

The Copy Local in Project References that you are trying applies only to referenced .NET assemblies. The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VC.PROJECT.REFERENCES%29&rd=true) are ambiguous and too terse on that. (Most often undistinguished use of "assembly" means .NET assembly rather than WinSxS assembly.)